# Conditional formatting if cell's text appears in another table

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have one sheet that has a large table of a bunch of names, about twenty rows and thirty columns.  On another sheet, I have a smaller table of names, all of which exist in the giant table.  How would I set up conditional formatting to highlight a cell if the name it holds appears in the smaller table?   I want to avoid an individual formula for each cell because there are about 600 different cells in the large table.

Comment: Do these tables have some unique ID? I understand that big one is an extended version of smaller one. But it's important if we search for duplicated values in whole table, without a structure (let's say that we find a cell with number 1 in small table and on this base we should format all cells with this number in bigger table).

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski I shouldve mentioned this in the OP, but there are no duplicate names within the same table.  There are no unique IDs though.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news.
Conditional formatting works only in current Sheet.
This topic was discussed here:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4490297?hl=en